# Having control flow issue with mongoose model's find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, koa

I'm completely new to node and it's frameworks Koa and express. I've a mongoose model called **Drawing** and a router module for that.

Problem is with express routers I was able the get the data from database using Drawing.find method but with Koa, control is not even going into Drawing.find. And I'm not able to get the data at all. Please find the following related code and help me understand the things better.

This is my router module

```
import * as Router from "koa-router";
import Drawing from "../../models/drawing";

function getRoutesForDrawing(): Router {
    console.log("Inside getRoutes for drawing");
    let route = new Router();
    route.get("/drawing", function(context,next) {
        console.log("Inside /drawing");
        Drawing.find(function(err,drawings) {
            console.log("Not gettig executed");
            context.body = "Welcome";
        });
        //context.body = "Welcome";       
    });
}
export default getRoutesForDrawing();
```

And the model is

```
import mongoose = require("mongoose");

export interface IDrawing extends mongoose.Document {
  drawingId:Number,
  drawingName:String,
  updatedOn:Date,
  updatedBy:Number
};

export const DrawingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  drawingId:Number,
  drawingName:String,
  updatedOn:Date,
  updatedBy:Number
});

const Drawing = mongoose.model<IDrawing>('Drawing', DrawingSchema);
export default Drawing;
```

As you can see in my router module, the control is actually coming for /drawing and it's printing in console "Inside /drawing" but then control isn't coming to Drawing.find. I'm getting difficulty in understanding this.

Comment: Not strictly related but never use the types `Number` and `String` in TypeScript. Use `number` and `string` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit hard to figure out what's going on because it looks like you have problems all over the place. Let me point out the things that stand out:

1. `getRoutesForDrawing` is declared to return a router and doesn't return anything
2. Koa routes are not like express. In particular they are not callback based. They take either generator functions (Koa 1.x) or async functions (Koa 2.x). You seem to expect that it's wanting a callback function which won't work. Assuming koa 2.x, its `router.get('/drawing', async(context) => {...});`
3. Assuming koa 2.x, you need to await the result of the mongoose methods, e.g. `context.body = await Drawing.find({})`

Comment: Makes sense... Could you provide a nice reference link if any where koa interacting with mongodb with what ever you've mentioned?

Comment: maybe this, although I haven't looked at how well done is is: https://github.com/rikukissa/koa-mongoose